# Numerical solution of differential equations, accuracy is not enough

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

```
Clear["Global`*"];
M1=17969/10000000;
M2=9/1000;
q=2/5;
Λ=143/50000;
c=q*(M2/M1)^2/2
v=Piecewise[{{Λ^4*((1+ph[t]^2/M1^2)^(q/2)-1), ph[t]>0},
             {Λ^4*(c*Tanh[ph[t]/M2]^2), ph[t]<=0}}];
vph=D[v,ph[t]];
ro=1/2*Λ^4*ph'[t]^2+v;
p=1/2*Λ^4*ph'[t]^2-v
s1=Flatten[NDSolve[
      {Λ^4*ph''[t]+3*Λ^4*A'[t]/A[t]*ph'[t]+vph==0,
      (Λ^4*A''[t])/A[t]==-(1/6)*(ro+3p),
      ph[0]==1321/250,
      ph'[0]==-(208213/200000000000),
      A[0]==1,
      A'[0]==57/2500000},
     {ph,A},{t,0,34.42349},
     MaxSteps->\[Infinity],WorkingPrecision->70]]
```

if I add the number of workingprecision, It will prompted to me

> "Error test failure at
> t==13.51983911114427669481141395951743899849861225404442210074803325679357077321916`60.;
> unable to continue."
> Additional supplementary：
> I ultimately need an image with such a physical parameter B[t]=-H'[t]/H[t]^2, and the H[t_]:=A'[t]/A[t]/.s1. If I don't adjust the accuracy,The Images of the B[t] is intermittent and inaccurate.If I can get as accurate as possible, The graph of B[t] will be smoothed out.So I want to improve the accuracy as much as possible, but I can only improve  WorkingPrecision->52 by using the above methods.

Can you help me with the answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, format properly your post. $\Lambda$ should appear as `Λ` or at least as `\[CapitalLambda]`, but not as `[CapitalLambda]`. When I paste your code in my notebook, I can a lot of errors due to formatting.

Comment: @yarchik Actually it's because OP hasn't put the code in a [code block](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), without that, "\" won't display in a post. The real problem is, values of `vph`, `ro`, `p` are missing.

Comment: Please show us the code text, rather than a screenshot. If you're having difficulty with code formating, check this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/1871

Comment: phi[t] is a function ,we need to solve for phi[t]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I doubt that `WorkingPrecision` is the issue. There is indeed a singularity at around 13.5 that physically correct equations should not have.

Comment: I get the same error with (t,0,1).  Might help to more easily read and understand the DE if you condense it to  canonical form without all the extra constants and notation.

Comment: Could it be the piecewise function that causes the singularity @yarchik